# Swift protocol of the map function

Tags: swift, generics

I would like to create protocol of types that can be mapped over.

Lets say my goal is to write a operator for map.  I realize this will not compile

```
func <^> <A,B,C>(f: (B) -> C, a: A<B>) -> A<C> {
    return a.map(f)
}
```

Now I would like to replace `A` with a protocol such that any object that has the map function can be used with this operator.

This is not allowed but what I would like to say is

```
protocol Maps {
    associatedtype E
    func map<T>(f: (E) -> T) -> Self<T>
}
```

The closest I can get to something that makes sense is as follows.  However it does not work correctly.

```
protocol Maps {
    associatedtype E
    func map<T, U: Maps>(f: (E) throws -> T) rethrows -> U where U.E == T
}


extension Array: Maps {
    func map<T, U>(f: (E) throws -> T) rethrows -> U where U : Maps, U.E == T {
        return try self.map(transform)
    }
}

func <^> <A,B,C,D>(f: (B) -> C, a: A) -> D where A: Maps, D: Maps, A.E == B, D.E == C {
    return a.map(f)
}
```

The main problem here being is that the map function does not return an `Array<T>` but a `Maps` protocol where `E` is `T`.

Should I just break down and write a `<^>` operator for every custom struct that can be mapped over?  Any suggestions will be appreciated!  Thanks

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve that requires you to do this? What's wrong with `a.map { f }`? Can you provide a usage example?

Comment: Your `Array` example cannot work. `self.map` will always return an array, not the type you will specify as `U`. Array can only specify `map<T>(f: (E) throws -> T) rethrows -> Array<T>` which is what the `Array.map` function is doing now. Your best option is to use operator overloading. You can have one operator definition for arrays and one operator for everything else.

Comment: Unfortunately, Swift doesn't support [higher-kinded types](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#higher-kinded-types) (yet) – so you cannot directly express the notion of `func map<T>(f: (E) -> T) -> Self<T>`.

Comment: Your `Maps` type seems strange. It contains a mapping for two unrelated types therefore I would call it `Mapper`. However, the result is a `Mapper`, too. I cannot say I understand that.

Comment: Maybe you can show an example of using this operator you want to define to help us understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Hamish Thank you for the link that is as I feared lets hope they implement this soon.